# Datetime equation returns no value. sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows

> string s = @"select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling='" +
>   mcCalendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString()

so i have this code. the mcCalendar has a value of '8/20/2013' because of toshortdatestring.
i just need to get all the rows from the date, mcCalendar.

so it is

> select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling='8/20/2013'

DateTimeofBilling on the Database table is a DateTime data type. sqlserver 2008

why cant i get the rows i expect to get using this code?

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* is that `ToShortDateString` isn't actually returning the value you want it to anyway, for cultural reasons. The right fix *isn't* to change the text handling - it's to use a parameterized query:

```
string sql = "select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling=@QueryDate";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@QueryDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = 
        mcCalendar.SelectionStart.Date;
    // Execute the command
}
```

*Always* use parameterized queries rather than building a SQL string containing values:

- It avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- It avoids data conversion issues like this one
- It helps to keep your *code* (the SQL) separate from the *data*, which makes it easier to see what's going on

Comment: @Volearix: That's not an appropriate edit. Edits are fine for *fixing* code or typos etc, but not changing the *style* of the code because you happen to dislike using `var` in this case.

Comment: i would just want to insert.

Comment: @JeoTalavera: Well your current code isn't doing an insert at all - it's doing a query. It's not clear why you're bringing up inserts now - but you should use parameterized SQL *either* way.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = @"select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling=CONVERT(date, '" + mcCalendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString() + "'); "
```

Should do what you're looking for (you didn't have a closing ' at the end). But yes, parameterized queries are a MUCH better way to go.

See if the following code returns results. If the naming of your field is correct, you might be looking specifically for '08/20/2013 12:00:00' without the conversion.

```
select * from Bill_Detail where CONVERT(date, DateTimeofBilling)='08/20/2013';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured to a UK style date (dd/mm/yyyy) instead of US style (mm/dd/yyyy) then that could be causing your problems. Try specifying you date as 'dd-mmm-yyyy'.

```
string queryDate = mcCalendar.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
string s = "SELECT * FROM Bill_Detail WHERE DateTimeofBilling = '" + queryDate + "'";
```

Comment: Why use a string representation at all? Parameterized queries for the win, IMO.

Comment: It's simpler. You're probably right though Jon, yours is probably a _better_ answer. I do dislike the use of var, however.

Comment: The use of `var` is a simple stylistic choice, and not essential to the answer at all. I don't actually think the code ends up simpler with the string conversion approach, personally - it's certainly not simpler to *read* with messy string concatenations.

Comment: Try it without the @ before the s string. The `mcCalendar.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");` works, and outputs the date in the format dd-MMM-yyyy. I haven't got an sql server handy at home to check, but the query _should_ work. Bare in mind that 21-Aug-2013 actually means 21-Aug-2013 00:00:00, so if your database entries have a time component then you may need to specify a date range rather than a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have removed the time element from your where clause.

For example if you have the value: "8/20/2013 00:00:00" then it will expect a full `DateTime` parameter.

There are couple of ways you could fix it.

1) Use the following SQL:

```
string s = @"select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling like '"
+ mcCalendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString() + "%'";
```

OR

2) Remove the "ToShortDateString" so that the parameter your passing through is a full Date and Time (mcCalendar.SelectionStart = 8/20/2013 00:00:00)

```
string s = @"select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling = '"
    + mcCalendar.SelectionStart + "'";
```

Comment: but the problem at the 2nd statement would be, that it would equate it to the hour,min and second. which i just want to get rows from the specific date.

Comment: When your rows are stored down to the database, do they have a value for the time portion of the date time?

If so then I would say try option 1, if not then it does not matter which option you choose to try.

Comment: "like" ddoesnt work on date time. it only works on string i think